# vba write data into listobject from collection (performance)

Tags: arrays, vba, collections, listobject

I am encountering low performance with writing data into a table (listobject)

I have a collection of objects and want to write them row by row into the table

```
For Each msrecord In mls.mlRecords
    Dim oNewRow As ListRow
    Set oNewRow = Sheets(mls.name).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = msrecord.id
Next msrecord
```

However this is too slow. I tried Application.ScreenUpdating = False with not success.

My idea is to fill an array first and then write it all at once into the table.

```
Dim outputArray As Variant

Dim counter As Long
For counter = 1 To mls.mlRecords.Count

    outputArray(counter, 1).Value = msrecord.id
    outputArray(counter, 2).Value = msrecord.name
    outputArray(counter, 3).Value = msrecord.morefields

 Next

 Sheets(mls.name).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value = outputArray
```

However, I now run into type mismatch error when assining values in the variant array. I can't really ReDim the array since I have a collection to start with.

Any thoughts? Does it make sense to build up the array first? How can I efficiently write data into table (listobjects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is not an array until it you call Redim. Prior to that it is Empty which is the default value of a Variant. Try adding this before your loop.

```
ReDim outputArray(1 to mls.mlRecords.Count, 1 to 3)
```

Comment: Ah ok ReDim based on the number of items in the collection. Works fine thanks! Now I have the issue that Sheets(mls.name).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value = outputArray only puts in the first row. I saw that you can resize based on a Range. However, this is again is then absolute based on the sheet where the table object is located, right? e.g. ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Resize Range("A1:D10)) Is there a way to resize "relative"  ListObjects("Table3").Resize(8,200) ??

Comment: Adding rows in a loop is again so slow...  For counter = 1 To mls.mlRecords.Count
                Sheets(mls.name).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add counter
            Next counter